# Gatsby V4 getNodesByType

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm currently migrating my Gatsby V3 to Gatsby V4.
I have a `createNode` using a function that retrieve some data from GraphQL using `getNodesByType("myType")`.

```
function getSecteur(realisation) {
const secteurs = getNodesByType(`StrapiSecteurs`);
console.log(secteurs)
if (realisation.client && realisation.client.secteur) {
  return secteurs.find(
    (secteur) => secteur.strapiId === realisation.client.secteur
  );
}


exports.onCreateNode = async ({
```

node,
actions,
getNodesByType,
}) => {
const { createNode } = actions;

```
if (node.internal.type === "StrapiRealisations") {
createNode({
  ...node,
  id: `${node.id}-markdown`,
  parent: node.id,
  children: [],
  client: {
    ...node.client,
    secteur: getSecteur(node),
  },
  citation: getCitation(node),
  internal: {
    type: "MDRealisation",
    contentDigest: digest(node),
  },
});
```

}

But in V4 this function does not retrieve any data, but I cannot found an alternative for getNodesByType.
Any idea(s) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
exports.sourceNodes = ({ actions, getNodesByType }) => {
  getNodesByType("StrapiSecteurs").forEach(node => actions.touchNode(node))
}
```

Comment: No I did not, should I add it where I'm calling my function ? (when I am creating my node something like that ?
createNode({
      ...node,
      id: `${node.id}-markdown`,
      parent: node.id,
      children: [],
      client: {
        ...node.client,
        secteur: exports.sourceNodes = ({ actions, getNodesByType }) => {
          getNodesByType("StrapiSecteurs").forEach(node => actions.touchNode(node))
        },
      },
      citation: getCitation(node),
      internal: {
        type: "MDRealisation",
        contentDigest: digest(node),
      },
    });
)

Comment: Please, edit the question, it's unreadable the code in the comment section. I want to see te full `sourceNode` or `onCreateNode`